# Redis using high memory with small data set

Tags: database, redis

I'm running redis-server and according to `prstat` it's utilizing 3721M of memory.  When I run `info` in redis-cli, I get this for memory:

```
used_memory:8739028 
used_memory_human:8.33M
used_memory_rss:8739028
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.00
```

This is running on a 2GB cloud instance, so my memory utilization is always over.  However, even when I `flushall` on redis it doesn't seem to effect the memory consumption.

Could this be do to a setting that maybe is allocating memory or any idea why redis is using so much over my actual data?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Also just to add, I'm running the same setup (application/redis) on another instance and the memory consumption is only 554M with `used_memory_human:5.68M` of data.

Response from pmap:

[root@]# pmap -x 27425

```
27425:  /opt/local/bin/redis-server /opt/local/etc/redis.conf
 Address  Kbytes     RSS    Anon  Locked Mode   Mapped File
08046000       8       8       8       - rw---    [ stack ]
08050000     208     160       -       - r-x--  redis-server
08093000       8       8       4       - rwx--  redis-server
08095000 3807836 3804160 3764928       - rwx--    [ heap ]
FE9BD000      12      12       -       - r-x--  libpthread.so.1
FEAF0000     456     456       -       - r-x--  libnsl.so.1
FEB72000       8       8       4       - rw---  libnsl.so.1
FEB74000      20      16       4       - rw---  libnsl.so.1
FEBA0000     304     304       -       - r-x--  libm.so.2
FEBFB000      16      16       -       - rwx--  libm.so.2
FEDA0000       4       4       -       - r--s-  dev:531,392 ino:3736139179
FEDB0000       4       4       -       - rwxs-    [ anon ]
FEDC0000      24      12       8       - rwx--    [ anon ]
FEDD0000       4       4       4       - rwx--    [ anon ]
FEDE0000    1216    1216       -       - r-x--  libc.so.1
FEF10000      36      36      24       - rwx--  libc.so.1
FEF19000       8       8       4       - rwx--  libc.so.1
FEF20000       4       4       4       - rwx--    [ anon ]
FEF30000      56      56       -       - r-x--  libsocket.so.1
FEF4E000       4       4       -       - rw---  libsocket.so.1
FEF50000       4       4       4       - rwx--    [ anon ]
FEF60000       4       4       -       - r-x--  libdl.so.1
FEF70000       4       4       -       - r--s-  ld.config
FEF80000       4       4       4       - rw---    [ anon ]
FEF90000       4       -       -       - rw---    [ anon ]
FEFA0000       4       4       4       - rwx--    [ anon ]
FEFB0000       4       4       -       - rwx--    [ anon ]
FEFB7000     208     208       -       - r-x--  ld.so.1
FEFFB000       8       8       4       - rwx--  ld.so.1
FEFFD000       4       4       -       - rwx--  ld.so.1
```

The limits has nothing enabled in the config, here's virtual memory and advanced:

```
VIRTUAL MEMORY
vm-enabled no
vm-swap-file /tmp/redis.swap
vm-max-memory 0
vm-page-size 32
vm-pages 134217728
vm-max-threads 4


ADVANCED CONFIG
hash-max-zipmap-entries 512
hash-max-zipmap-value 64
```

Comment: What version of Redis? Who are you hosting with? Did you install Redis yourself? And what does your redis.conf look like? Might get us closer to figuring out what is going on.

Comment: @j.w.r, Redis version 2.2.2, hosted with Joyent, installed redis myself.  Should I paste the whole config or is there any particular items to post?

Comment: The 'limits', 'virtual memory' (if it exists), and 'advanced' sections of the config should be fine. Also, what was the SIZE and RSS values from prstat? The 3721M number sounds like SIZE which includes VM/shared memory/memory mapped files and can be misleading, RSS is usually what I look at. Try running `pmap -x PID-of-redis` instead and post what that outputs.

Comment: @j.w.r, thank you just updated with the results from pmap.  From prstat, SIZE is 3721M and RSS are 3716M

Comment: sorry for slow response, been busy.. Another question: When was  this process started? Has it been running for hours, days, weeks, etc.

Comment: @j.w.r, no problem! It's been running for about two months.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old but I had this issue before.  If I remember correctly, I shutdown my redis instance, deleted the RDB file if applicable and restart redis.  *If don't want to remove the RDB file because it contains data you need, I do NOT recommend this.*  You can try to  `DEL` what you can, then do a `SAVE` (I believe redis does `SAVE` when it's shutdown so that might be redundant) and then restart.

It would be good time to upgrade redis to latest stable if you haven't.